# How to install alexa in raspberry Pi zero w

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Hi I try to install alexa on raspberry Pi zero but it is throwing some error. Pls help me on this and please share me the correct git link to use alexa in RPI zero w.
The steps which are available on the internet are not comparable with the RPI zero . Pls help me to complete my project

Installing alexa in RPI zero

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share any error, so it's difficult to see where is the issue. There is a guide that provides step-by-step instructions to set up the Alexa Voice Service (AVS) Device SDK on a Raspberry Pi from source, if this what you are trying to do. Please find more information here: https://developer.amazon.com/de-DE/docs/alexa/avs-device-sdk/raspberry-pi.html